# Lanix X110 (Mexican made, generic android 4.4.2 OS) Random "ghost" apps appear from nowhere and other issues

Tags: operating-system

I have some issues with my phone and I hope someone could help me
when I arrived home  just found in my phone some random apps with the "system" logo in them, like in this case those were named launcher

[image: Random "system" apps]

I stumbled across some apps like that in the past and I unistalled them but im scared that if I uninstall those my phone's OS gets corrupted

Because it had happened to me before but it was after getting an e-mail from a teacher and I coulnt recover even after doing a factory recovery so I sent it to warranty

Another issue I had in the past its that its way too slow, it takes a lot of time to just open google maps
Another one consist in not being able to detect any wi-fi network at all

The last issue I had (and the reason I had to root it) its some full screen and sometimes inapropiate ads that appeared in the lock screen, system settings, home screen, and other system apps

I hope you guys have some answers and suggestions on that 
Regards

Comment: Hey guys im back, with this issue, as those adware keeps on coming back, even trough i've deleted those apps, but they keep on coming back, and its now annoying as it installs more and more, in that case what do I do, I dont want to factory reset, also that the fact that dr web detects the system calculator as a virus

Answer (score 1):

Do this. Those are brought to you by some app integrated to system. If you could be kin enough you could realize that even advertisements appear on status bar and or drawn over other normal apps. But though even if you haven't seen ads in your phone, automatic installation only is too worse an issue to live with.

1. Snatch Dr.Web antivirus from any source you're convenient with,
2. Install it and then run a full system scan.
3. Take note of Adware originated apps, binaries, and frameworks if possible. The app reports Google Play Services also as an adware but don't delete it.
4. Since you have kingroot, install a root file manager like Es File Explorer, or most preferably Solid Explorer and grant it root access.
5. Navigate to the reported files and delete them except Google Play Services.
6. Get back to kingroot and remove root access. Reboot your phone and you'll be good.

I did this on my Sony and all those things went away

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for your comment about Es, the questioner should then look for some other root app to get rid of the infected files. You can recommend an app so that I can refine my answer

Comment: @beeshyams Okay I'll do that

Comment: I used Avira Antivirus as i've used that one in the past, and it deleted the files from me, fixing issue #1 (and the main one)